# Converting repmat (matlab) into tile (python)

Tags: python, matlab, tile

I am trying to convert this piece of code written in MATLAB into Python:

```
center = repmat([11; 13], 1, length(x)); %where length x = 749
```

the first row is all 11 and second row is all 13 (so 2 x 749)

How do I reproduce this in Python? Here is what I have so far:

```
x_center = 11
z_center = 13
center = np.tile([x_center,z_center],(2,374))
```

This creates 2 x 748 with both rows alternating between 11 and 13. I'm not familiar with Python so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I was able to get it

```
x_center = 11
z_center = 13
tile_x_center = np.tile(x_center,(1,len(x[0])))
tile_z_center = np.tile(z_center,(1,len(x[0])))
center = np.tile([tile_x_center,tile_z_center],1)
```